# Zend 2 terribly slow on Azure

Tags: azure, zend-framework2

I try to deploying a Zend 2 application on Azure webservices. I installed a custom a PHP 5.5, so I am able to use the intl extension.
Everything works but the Zend application takes 'forever' to load. It is a pretty basic Zend 2 installation without any performance enhancements yet.

[image: xdebug-stack-trace]

Any ideas on finding out what is going on?

Comment: Have you benchmarked the process? Try using xdebug and profile the app. You can use KCacheGrind to view the profiled processes and get an idea of which part take a long time to run.

Comment: There is no such thing `Azure webservices`. It is either Azure Web Sites or Cloud Service (Web Role). It appears you are using Web Role, but is not definite from your question. Could you elaborate and provide more clear definition of your problem including what you have tried to solve the problem along with benchmarks from other machines of similar configuration (CPU/RAM).

Comment: It is what Azure calls a "Web Site". I am running the same application now on a 'Extra Small' Azure-VM with Debian. There the home page loads in 0.050sec. The home page uses no database connection. As can be seen from the xdebug trace above is appears to be the loading of the ZendFramework that takes forever, which could point to disk I/O. I just don't know where to look, or what I could try to solve the problem.